# Sequelize list of functions on the object

Tags: sequelize.js

Is there a way in using Sequelize (sequelizejs.com) to output all the functions magically created on objects when I set associations.

for example; I have a User model and I set

`User.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Friends', through: 'UserFriend' });`

now i can call

```
User.create({
    name: Faker.name.findName()
 }).then((user) => {
     user.createFriend({
         name: Faker.name.findName()
     })
});
```

The `createFriend` function is possible because of the belongsToMany relation.

Is there a way to output all functions created on User (or user)?

Sometimes to me it's not really clear what I can call on a object, it would help me if i could output it in some way.

Comment: Can't you just debug it inside promise's fulfilled callback?

Comment: you mean console-ing the user object? I cannot find any reference to createFriend there, so it seem (as i would expect) to be a magic function

Comment: Well, I don't know how you are debugging it, but if used with node-inspector then in Chrome Dev Tools you can see the body of the function

Comment: I just use terminal, but using Chrome sounds way better xD I'll look into that, thanks

Answer (score 20):

I wasn't able to find a way to easily log out all of the magic functions. But if you take a look at the source code they're all under accessors for each type of relationship with explanations on what they do.

`sequelize/lib/associations/` - https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/tree/main/lib/associations

Belongs-To-Many:

```
get: 'get' + plural,
set: 'set' + plural,
addMultiple: 'add' + plural,
add: 'add' + singular,
create: 'create' + singular,
remove: 'remove' + singular,
removeMultiple: 'remove' + plural,
hasSingle: 'has' + singular,
hasAll: 'has' + plural,
count: 'count' + plural
```

Belongs-To:

```
get: 'get' + singular,
set: 'set' + singular,
create: 'create' + singular
```

Has-Many:

```
get: 'get' + plural,
set: 'set' + plural,
addMultiple: 'add' + plural,
add: 'add' + singular,
create: 'create' + singular,
remove: 'remove' + singular,
removeMultiple: 'remove' + plural,
hasSingle: 'has' + singular,
hasAll: 'has' + plural,
count: 'count' + plural
```

Has-One:

```
get: 'get' + singular,
set: 'set' + singular,
create: 'create' + singular
```

Comment: This helps! Still an output of the generated functions would be a great feature. Maybe I'll have to feature request it.

Comment: is there getA for plural... lets say user has many friends i want to get a friend who matches certain criteria

Answer (score 13):

I also ran into this issue so I did some digging and came up with a way to list out all of the useful attributes/association functions/common functions. Keep in mind some of these functions may have one or more parameters. This may also not work with your version of Sequelize as I am digging quite deep into the internals to output this data and they are of course subject to change. Hopefully this helps you!

```
const models = require('./models');

for (let model of Object.keys(models)) {
  if(!models[model].name)
    continue;

  console.log("\n\n----------------------------------\n", 
  models[model].name, 
  "\n----------------------------------");

  console.log("\nAttributes");
  for (let attr of Object.keys(models[model].attributes)) {
      console.log(models[model].name + '.' + attr);
  }

  console.log("\nAssociations");
  for (let assoc of Object.keys(models[model].associations)) {
    for (let accessor of Object.keys(models[model].associations[assoc].accessors)) {
      console.log(models[model].name + '.' + models[model].associations[assoc].accessors[accessor]+'()');
    }
  }

  console.log("\nCommon");
  for (let func of Object.keys(models[model].Instance.super_.prototype)) {
    if(func === 'constructor' || func === 'sequelize')
      continue;
    console.log(models[model].name + '.' + func+'()');
  }
}
```

and the output will look something like:

```
 ----------------------------------
 Assignment
 ----------------------------------

 Attributes
 Assignment.id
 Assignment.type
 Assignment.type_id
 Assignment.created_at
 Assignment.updated_at
 Assignment.user_id
 Assignment.reporter_id

 Associations
 Assignment.getUser()
 Assignment.setUser()
 Assignment.createUser()
 Assignment.getReporter()
 Assignment.setReporter()
 Assignment.createReporter()
 Assignment.getPost_assignment()
 Assignment.setPost_assignment()
 Assignment.createPost_assignment()
 Assignment.getHistory()
 Assignment.setHistory()
 Assignment.addHistory()
 Assignment.addHistory()
 Assignment.createHistory()
 Assignment.removeHistory()
 Assignment.removeHistory()
 Assignment.hasHistory()
 Assignment.hasHistory()
 Assignment.countHistory()

 Common
 Assignment.where()
 Assignment.toString()
 Assignment.getDataValue()
 Assignment.setDataValue()
 Assignment.get()
 Assignment.set()
 Assignment.setAttributes()
 Assignment.changed()
 Assignment.previous()
 Assignment._setInclude()
 Assignment.save()
 Assignment.reload()
 Assignment.validate()
 Assignment.hookValidate()
 Assignment.update()
 Assignment.updateAttributes()
 Assignment.destroy()
 Assignment.restore()
 Assignment.increment()
 Assignment.decrement()
 Assignment.equals()
 Assignment.equalsOneOf()
 Assignment.setValidators()
 Assignment.toJSON()
```

Answer (score 4):

For any future visitor TeeTwoEx code doesn't work as of the present date BUT if you are only looking to get only the functions of you models like yours truly :) there is a way to work it around . TeeTwoEx saving lives and soul sanity years after an unsung hero if you ask me .

```js
const models = require('./src/models/index');

for (let model of Object.keys(models)) {
  if(models[model].name === 'Sequelize')
     continue;
  if(!models[model].name)
    continue;

  console.log("\n\n----------------------------------\n", 
  models[model].name, 
  "\n----------------------------------");

  
  console.log("\nAssociations");
  for (let assoc of Object.keys(models[model].associations)) {
    for (let accessor of Object.keys(models[model].associations[assoc].accessors)) {
      console.log(models[model].name + '.' + models[model].associations[assoc].accessors[accessor]+'()');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner to get the list of specific  magic method functions for your model.

However, it requires you to get an **instance (row item)** of the model.

```
console.log(Object.keys(MODEL-INSTANCE-ITEM.__proto__))
```

For example, working on the Campus model, associated with a Students model:

```
const rowInstanceOfCampus = Campus.create({
  name: "MIT", 
  location: "Massachusetts"
}) 

console.log(Object.keys(rowInstanceOfCampus.__proto__))

// console log output
[
  '_customGetters',    '_customSetters',
  'validators',        '_hasCustomGetters',
  '_hasCustomSetters', 'rawAttributes',
  '_isAttribute',      'getStudents',
  'countStudents',     'hasStudent',
  'hasStudents',       'setStudents',
  'addStudent',        'addStudents',
  'removeStudent',     'removeStudents',
  'createStudent'
]
```